# How to add items to a Javascript data array/object

Tags: javascript

I'm not an expert with JavaScript!

I have a simple array/object that I need to add to a JavaScript table.
Something like this:

```
var columns = {
                "0": { "styles": "width:22%;" },
                "1": { "styles": "width:13%;" },
                "2": { "styles": "width:13%;" },
                "3": { "styles": "width:13%;" },
                "4": { "styles": "width:13%;" },
                "5": { "styles": "width:13%;" },
                "6": { "styles": "width:13%;" }
            };
```

However the "columns" variable has to change depending on how many records I have... so 0 will always be the same (22%) but 1-5 depends on how many columns defined by user and 6 is a "total" column. The width of 1-6 will change as well.

I know how to get the number of columns but just not sure how I create the list of columns and produce something like above "column" declaration.

Comment: Technically the above structure is an object not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTable'), // table to perform search on
    row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0],
    columnsCount = row.getElementsByTagName('td').length,
    columns = {0: { styles: 'width: 22%' }};

for (var i = 1; i < columnsCount; i++) {
  columns[i] = {styles: 'width: ' + Math.floor((100-22) / (columnsCount - 1)) + '%'}

  row.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].style = columns[i].styles;
}

console.log(columns);
```

Here is an working example: http://jqversion.com/#!/afxvKvE

Answer (score 1):

```
var columns = [
    { "styles": "width:22%;" },
    { "styles": "width:13%;" },
    { "styles": "width:13%;" },
    { "styles": "width:13%;" },
    { "styles": "width:13%;" },
    { "styles": "width:13%;" },
    { "styles": "width:13%;" }
    ];

// add a elements to array
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     var width = '12'; // whatever width you want for each element.
     columns.push( '{ "styles": "width:' + width + '%;" }' );
}
```

Comment: How do I include 0 - 6 "1": {"styles":"width:13%"}

Comment: They are implicit - elements 0..6 are in the initialiser above

Comment: I think you have mistaken with your quotes: it's `columns.push({"styles": "width:" + width + "%;"});`

Comment: Haven't had my 3 Shredded Wheat :-)